# How do you express a surface of revolution as the graph of a function?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, surfaces, cylindrical-coordinates, solid-of-revolution

Consider a real function $f$ with domain non-negative real numbers.
Let $y = f(x)$, and consider the surface traced out
by rotating the graph of $f$ about the $y$-axis.
This surface is the graph of some function $y = F(x,z)$.
How do we express $F$ in terms of $f$?

Comment: locally only pieces of a  revolution's surface can be parametrized à la Monge, the basic example is an hemisphere  of a sphere

Comment: @janmarqz It sounds like you're thinking more generally than what I wanted to post here. (My title is more general than the question in the body).

Comment: generally is general, Mike

Answer (score 1):

The point $(x,z)$ in the plane will have distance $r = \sqrt{x^2 + z^2}$ from the origin. The surface is radially symmetric, and the value of $F$ depends only on the value of $f$ at this distance from the origin. That is, $$F(x,z) = f\left(\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\right)\,.$$